# Evaluating $\int_{1/\phi^2}^{1}\frac{\log^2x}{1-x}\ \log^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^2\right)\ \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I want to calculate the following integral:
$$I=\int_{1/\phi^2}^{1}\frac{\log^2x}{1-x}\ \log^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^2\right)\ \mathrm{d}x$$
where $\phi=(\sqrt{5}+1)/2$ is the golden ratio, so $1/\phi^2 = (3-\sqrt 5)/2$.

Can Mathematica give a closed form answer for $I$ (even if it is in terms of some special functions like the Riemann zeta function)?

The following code returns unevaluated:

```
Integrate[
 Log[x]^2/(1 - x) Log[1/x ((1 - x)/(1 + x))^2]^2, {x, 1/GoldenRatio^2, 1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is as close as I've been able to get:

First, I rewrite your integrand a little:

$\frac {\mathrm {log}[x]^2} {(1 - 
      x)} \mathrm {log}[\frac {1} {x} (\frac {1 - x} {1 + 
          x})^2]^2 $ = $\frac {\mathrm {log}[x]^2} {(1 - 
     x)} (-\mathrm {log}[x] + 
     2 (\mathrm {log}[1 - x] - \mathrm {log}[1 + x]))^2 $

I input this as:

```
part1=Log[x]^2/(1 - x);
part2 = (-Log[x] + 2 (Log[1 - x] - Log[1 + x]))^2;
integrand= part1*part2;
```

Then define this alternating function (it will come in handy in a second):

```
altFun[n_] = 1/2 (1 - (-1)^n (-1 + Log[x]) + Log[x]);
```

observe the coefficients of the expansion of `part2` at $x=0$ follow a kind of regular pattern when divided by `altFun`:

```
expansionPart2 = (Table[{n, 
    SeriesCoefficient[(-Log[x] + 2 (Log[1 - x] - Log[1 + x]))^2, {x, 
       0, n}]/altFun[n]}, {n, 0, 30}])

(*{{0, Log[x]^2}, {1, 8}, {2, 16}, {3, 8/3}, {4, 32/3}, {5, 8/5}, {6, 
  368/45}, {7, 8/7}, {8, 704/105}, ... *)
```

The odd n terms are just $\frac{8}{n}$. We can find the even terms by using `FindSequenceFunction`:

```
odds[n_] = 8/n;

evens[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[no[[3 ;; All ;; 2]], n]

(*-((16 (-2 + PolyGamma[0, 3/2] - PolyGamma[0, 1/2 + n/2]))/n)*)
```

and the $n=0$ term is $\mathrm{log[x]^2}$.

we can now create a function that generates the $n$th expansion term at $x=0$ for $part2$:

```
seqFun[n_] = 
 FullSimplify[
  PiecewiseExpand[
   x^n*altFun[n]*
    Piecewise[{{odds[n], Mod[n, 2] == 1}, {evens[n], 
       Mod[n, 2] == 0 && n > 0}, {Log[x]^2, n == 0}}]]]
```

This results in

$\begin{equation}
\mathrm{seqFun[n]} = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
    8 x^n \frac{\mathrm{log[x]}}{n}, & \text{odd n } \\
    (16 x^n (\mathrm{HarmonicNumber}[1/2 (-1 + n)] + \mathrm{Log[4]}))/n, & \text{even n, n>0 } \\
 (\mathrm{Log[x]}^2 & \text{n = 0 }
\end{array}
\right\}
\end{equation}$

we now can multiply `seqFun` by `part1` and get integral for each term:

```
seqInt[n_] = 
 PiecewiseExpand[part1*seqFun[n]];
indef = Integrate[serInt[n], x];
x0=1/GoldenRatio^2;
defInt = 
 FullSimplify[PiecewiseExpand[(indef /. x -> 1) - (indef /. x -> x0)],
   n >= 1]
```

This yields a very complicated expression that doesn't format well here:
$\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{32 \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)^{-2 (n+1)} \left(H_{\frac{n-1}{2}}+\log (4)\right) \left(-4^{n+1} \left(\Phi \left(\frac{1}{\phi ^2},3,n+1\right)+2 \text{csch}^{-1}(2) \Phi \left(\frac{1}{\phi ^2},2,n+1\right)\right)-\left(\left(\sqrt{5}+3\right) \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)^{2 n} \left(4 \text{csch}^{-1}(2)^2 B_{\frac{1}{\phi ^2}}(n+1,0)+\psi ^{(2)}(n+1)\right)\right)\right)}{n} & (n \bmod 2)=0 \\
 \frac{8 \left(3\ 2^{2 n+3} \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)^{-2 (n+1)} \left(\Phi \left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}+3},4,n+1\right)+2 \text{csch}^{-1}(2) \left(\Phi \left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}+3},3,n+1\right)+\text{csch}^{-1}(2) \Phi \left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}+3},2,n+1\right)\right)\right)+8 \text{csch}^{-1}(2)^3 B_{\frac{1}{\phi ^2}}(n+1,0)-\psi ^{(3)}(n+1)\right)}{n} & (n \bmod 2)=1 \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$

This is a screenshot of the output which looks a little easier to read:
[image]
You may notice that I ran `FullSimplify` on `defInt` with the assumption $n\geq1$. This is because `indef/.{x->1,n->0}` results in `Indeterminate`, but we can evaluate the $n=0$ case separately and take the limit as $x->1$:

```
int0 = Integrate[seqInt[0], x];

p0 = Limit[int0, x -> 1] - (int0 /. x -> x0)
(* 16 Log[1 - 1/GoldenRatio^2] Log[GoldenRatio]^4 - 
 32 Log[GoldenRatio]^3 PolyLog[2, 1/GoldenRatio^2] - 
 48 Log[GoldenRatio]^2 PolyLog[3, 1/GoldenRatio^2] - 
 48 Log[GoldenRatio] PolyLog[4, 1/GoldenRatio^2] - 
 24 PolyLog[5, 1/GoldenRatio^2] + 24 Zeta[5] *)
```

So now we have calculated the definite integral `defInt` for each term, and we just need to sum from $n=1,...,\infty$ to get the result:

```
result = p0 + Sum[defInt, {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

The infinite sum unfortunately does not evaluate for me. But we can plot the partial sum and see it approaches the value of `NIntegrate`:

```
partSum := p0 + Sum[defInt, {n, 1, nMax}];
nResult = NIntegrate[integrand, {x, x0, 1}];
DiscretePlot[{nResult, partSum}, {nMax, 1, 300, 10}, Joined -> True, 
 Filling -> None]
```

[image]

I am not sure how feasible it is to find a closed form to `DiscreteLimit[partSum, nMax -> Infinity]`, but this is at least much closer to a closed form.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. +1. I need a simplified answer. Please simplify your answer. I will with utmost respect accept your answer

Comment: I will update answer if I make anymore progress. I am also looking at if I can use the series coefficients from `AsymptoticIntegrate` and plug them into `FindGeneratingFunction` to get a closed form for the indefinite integral, but I have not had luck with this yet.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much. I will wait for your updated answer. Please comment after updating the answer

Comment: I haven't been able to make any more progress, and I don't think I will be able to find a closed form for the infinite sum. Have you considered posting to the mathematics SE? There are some really talented integrators over there

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your effort. I will try it in MSE. Thanks.